# How to forbid empty list initialization?

Tags: c++11, c++14, default-constructor, list-initialization, deleted-functions

I have a class, that doesn't have any members at all. And so, it is not intended to be instantiated. So, I deleted default c-r. That forbids any construction except list-initialization. Is there any way to forbid it too?

```
class Empty{
//No non-static data members
Empty()=delete;
};

Empty A{};// is allowed
Empty A ={};//is allowed too
//Empty A; ok, forbidden
//Empty A=Empty(); ok, forbidden
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Empty A{};` works because `Empty` is an [aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). Merely deleting the default constructor is insufficient to prevent it from being an aggregate (in C++17; in C++20, this will work).

The simplest way to do this is to give it a private member, of type `char` so that the type's size won't change. Alternatively, you can give it a private default constructor that isn't `= default`ed.

However, just because a type is not meant to be used to make an object does not mean you should take special care to *prevent* it from doing so. `std::enable_if<blah>` is a type too, and objects of that type are not meant to be constructed. But you can still do it.

You shouldn't take these steps unless there is a genuine *problem* that would be caused by the user creating an object of that type.

Comment: Another ugly hack would be adding a user-provided constructor, e.g. `Empty(dummy) {};  private: struct dummy{};`